# how to compare two string in python ? I am getting this error

Tags: python

Code syntax:

```
if( email_from1 != email_from2 & email_subject1 != email_subject2):
```

Error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: [List of Python operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_basic_operators.htm)

Answer (score 3):

In python `&` is a bitwise operator.  It appears you need the logical operator, which would be `and`.  In addition in Python you do not need the `()` around the expresion for an `if`.  But using tuples you can just do:

```
if email_from1, email_subject1 != email_from2, email_subject2:
```

Answer (score 2):

Python '&' doesn't work with strings. It's a Bitwise Operator. use 'and' instead:
eg 1:

```
a = 'omi'
b ='not omi'
c ='omi'

if a == c && b!=c:
    print "hello"
```

output:

```
  File "test.py", line 5
    if a == c && b!=c:
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

eg2 :

```
a = 'omi'
b ='not omi'
c ='omi'

if a == c and b!=c:
    print "hello"
```

output:

```
hello
```

could you try so :

```
if( email_from1 != email_from2 and email_subject1 != email_subject2):
```