# python 3 error unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python-3.x

```py
def temperature():
    A=str(input("enter your unit"))
    B=str(input("enter your conversion unit"))
    C=int(input("enter temperature"))
    if A=="c"  & B=="f":
        print("your temp in fahrenheit is",C*9/5+32,"f")
    elif A=="c" & B=="k":
        print("your temp in kelvin is",C+273.15,"k")
    elif A=="f" & B=="c":
        print("your temp in celsius is",C-32*5/9,"c")
    elif A=="f" & B=="k":
        print("your temp in kelvin is",C+459.67,"k")
    elif A=="k" & B=="c":
        print("your temp in celsius is",C+273.15,"c")
    elif A=="k" & B=="f":
        print("your temp in fahrenheit is",C-273.15*9/5+32,"f")
    else:
        print("not valid")

temperature()
```

when i run this code it throws the following error:

```
File "D:\PYTHON PROGRAMS\if and else\temperature.py", line 20, in <module>
    temperature()  
File "D:\PYTHON PROGRAMS\if and else\temperature.py", line 5, in temperature
    if A=="c"  & B=="f":

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

please help me with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to compare two string in python ? I am getting this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395086/how-to-compare-two-string-in-python-i-am-getting-this-error)

Answer (score 0):

Use `and` instead of `&`, in python `&` is the bitwise and (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=bitwise#binary-bitwise-operations)